# How to use gekko to control two variables while manipulating two variables for a cstr?

Tags: gekko

Attached below is my PYTHON code:

I have a CSTR and im trying to control the height of the tank and the temperature while manipulating the inlet flow and the cooling temperature. The problem is that the CV's are not tracking their respective setpoints. I tried doing the problem for only 1 CV and 1 MV, it worked really well.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from gekko import GEKKO

# Steady State Initial Condition
u1_ss = 280.0
u2_ss=100.0
# Feed Temperature (K)
Tf = 350
# Feed Concentration (mol/m^3)
Caf = 1

# Steady State Initial Conditions for the States
Ca_ss = 1
T_ss = 304
h_ss=94.77413303
V_ss=8577.41330293

x0 = np.empty(4)
x0[0] = Ca_ss
x0[1] = T_ss
x0[2]= h_ss
x0[3]= V_ss

#%% GEKKO nonlinear MPC
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = [0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.1,0.12,0.15,0.2]


c1=10.0
Ac=100.0

# Density of A-B Mixture (kg/m^3)
rho = 1000
# Heat capacity of A-B Mixture (J/kg-K)
Cp = 0.239
# Heat of reaction for A->B (J/mol)
mdelH = 5e4
# E - Activation energy in the Arrhenius Equation (J/mol)
# R - Universal Gas Constant = 8.31451 J/mol-K
EoverR = 8750
# Pre-exponential factor (1/sec)
k0 = 7.2e10
# U - Overall Heat Transfer Coefficient (W/m^2-K)
# A - Area - this value is specific for the U calculation (m^2)
UA = 5e4

# initial conditions
Tc0 = 280
T0 = 304
Ca0 = 1.0
h0=94.77413303
q0=100.0
V0=8577.41330293

tau = m.Const(value=0.5)
Kp = m.Const(value=1)

m.Tc = m.MV(value=Tc0,lb=250,ub=350)
m.T = m.CV(value=T_ss)
m.h= m.CV(value=h0)
m.rA = m.Var(value=0)
m.Ca = m.CV(value=Ca_ss,lb=0,ub=1)
m.V= m.CV(value=V_ss,lb=0,ub=100000)
m.q=m.MV(value=q0,lb=0,ub=100000)

m.Equation(m.rA == k0*m.exp(-EoverR/m.T)*m.Ca)

m.Equation(m.T.dt() == m.q/m.V*(Tf - m.T) \
            + mdelH/(rho*Cp)*m.rA \
            + UA/m.V/rho/Cp*(m.Tc-m.T))

m.Equation(m.Ca.dt() == m.q/m.V*(Caf - m.Ca) - m.rA)
m.Equation(m.h.dt()==(m.q-c1*m.h**0.5)/Ac)
m.Equation(m.V.dt() == m.q- c1*m.h**0.5)

#MV tuning
m.Tc.STATUS = 1
m.Tc.FSTATUS = 0
m.Tc.DMAX = 100
m.Tc.DMAXHI = 20   
m.Tc.DMAXLO = -100 

m.q.STATUS = 1
m.q.FSTATUS = 0
m.q.DMAX = 10

#CV tuning
m.T.STATUS = 1
m.T.FSTATUS = 1
m.T.TR_INIT = 1
m.T.TAU = 1.0
DT = 0.5 # deadband

m.h.STATUS = 1
m.h.FSTATUS = 1
m.h.TR_INIT = 1
m.h.TAU = 1.0

m.Ca.STATUS = 1
m.Ca.FSTATUS = 0 # no measurement
m.Ca.TR_INIT = 0

m.V.STATUS = 1
m.V.FSTATUS = 0 # no measurement
m.V.TR_INIT = 0

m.options.CV_TYPE = 1
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.SOLVER = 3

#%% define CSTR model
def cstr(x,t,u1,u2,Tf,Caf,Ac):
    # Inputs (3):
    # Temperature of cooling jacket (K)
    Tc = u1
    q=u2
    # Tf = Feed Temperature (K)
    # Caf = Feed Concentration (mol/m^3)

    # States (2):
    # Concentration of A in CSTR (mol/m^3)
    Ca = x[0]
    # Temperature in CSTR (K)
    T = x[1]
    # the height of the tank (m)

    h=x[2]

    V=x[3]

    # Parameters:

    # Density of A-B Mixture (kg/m^3)
    rho = 1000
    # Heat capacity of A-B Mixture (J/kg-K)
    Cp = 0.239
    # Heat of reaction for A->B (J/mol)
    mdelH = 5e4
    # E - Activation energy in the Arrhenius Equation (J/mol)
    # R - Universal Gas Constant = 8.31451 J/mol-K
    EoverR = 8750
    # Pre-exponential factor (1/sec)
    k0 = 7.2e10
    # U - Overall Heat Transfer Coefficient (W/m^2-K)
    # A - Area - this value is specific for the U calculation (m^2)
    UA = 5e4
    # reaction rate
    rA = k0*np.exp(-EoverR/T)*Ca

    # Calculate concentration derivative
    dCadt = q/V*(Caf - Ca) - rA
    # Calculate temperature derivative
    dTdt = q/V*(Tf - T) \
            + mdelH/(rho*Cp)*rA \
            + UA/V/rho/Cp*(Tc-T)
    # Calculate height derivative

    dhdt=(q-c1*h**0.5)/Ac
    if x[2]>=300 and dhdt>0:
       dhdt = 0

    dVdt= q-c1*h**0.5 

    # Return xdot:
    xdot = np.zeros(4)
    xdot[0] = dCadt
    xdot[1] = dTdt
    xdot[2]= dhdt
    xdot[3]= dVdt

    return xdot


# Time Interval (min)
t = np.linspace(0,8,401)

# Store results for plotting
Ca = np.ones(len(t)) * Ca_ss
V=np.ones(len(t))*V_ss
T = np.ones(len(t)) * T_ss
Tsp = np.ones(len(t)) * T_ss
hsp=np.ones(len(t))*h_ss
h=np.ones(len(t))*h_ss
u1 = np.ones(len(t)) * u1_ss
u2 = np.ones(len(t)) * u2_ss

# Set point steps
Tsp[0:100] = 330.0
Tsp[100:200] = 350.0
Tsp[230:260] = 370.0
Tsp[260:290] = 390.0

hsp[0:100] = 30.0
hsp[100:200] =60.0
hsp[200:250]=90.0

# Create plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.ion()
plt.show()

# Simulate CSTR
for i in range(len(t)-1):
    # simulate one time period (0.05 sec each loop)
    ts = [t[i],t[i+1]]
    y = odeint(cstr,x0,ts,args=(u1[i+1],u2[i+1],Tf,Caf,Ac))

    # retrieve measurements
    Ca[i+1] = y[-1][0]
    T[i+1] = y[-1][1]
    h[i+1]= y[-1][2]
    V[i+1]= y[-1][3]

    # insert measurement
    m.T.MEAS = T[i+1]
    m.h.MEAS=h[i+1]
    # solve MPC
    m.solve(disp=True)

    m.T.SPHI = Tsp[i+1] + DT
    m.T.SPLO = Tsp[i+1] - DT

    m.h.SPHI = hsp[i+1] + DT
    m.h.SPLO = hsp[i+1] - DT

    # retrieve new Tc value
    u1[i+1] = m.Tc.NEWVAL
    u2[i+1] = m.q.NEWVAL
    # update initial conditions
    x0[0] = Ca[i+1]
    x0[1] = T[i+1]
    x0[2]= h[i+1]
    x0[3]= V[i+1]

    #%% Plot the results
    plt.clf()
    plt.subplot(6,1,1)
    plt.plot(t[0:i],u1[0:i],'b--',linewidth=3)
    plt.ylabel('Cooling T (K)')
    plt.legend(['Jacket Temperature'],loc='best')

    plt.subplot(6,1,2)
    plt.plot(t[0:i],u2[0:i],'b--',linewidth=3)
    plt.ylabel('inlet flow')


    plt.subplot(6,1,3)
    plt.plot(t[0:i],Ca[0:i],'b.-',linewidth=3,label=r'$C_A$')
    plt.plot([0,t[i-1]],[0.2,0.2],'r--',linewidth=2,label='limit')
    plt.ylabel(r'$C_A$ (mol/L)')
    plt.legend(loc='best')

    plt.subplot(6,1,4)

    plt.plot(t[0:i],V[0:i],'g--',linewidth=3)
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('Volume of Tank')

    plt.subplot(6,1,5)
    plt.plot(t[0:i],Tsp[0:i],'k-',linewidth=3,label=r'$T_{sp}$')
    plt.plot(t[0:i],T[0:i],'b.-',linewidth=3,label=r'$T_{meas}$')
    plt.plot([0,t[i-1]],[400,400],'r--',linewidth=2,label='limit')
    plt.ylabel('T (K)')
    plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
    plt.legend(loc='best')

    plt.subplot(6,1,6)

    plt.plot(t[0:i],hsp[0:i],'g--',linewidth=3,label=r'$h_{sp}$')
    plt.plot(t[0:i],h[0:i],'k.-',linewidth=3,label=r'$h_{meas}$')
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('tank level')
    plt.legend(loc='best')


    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```